# Finding contiguity by comparing kmers in R

Tags: r, string, string-comparison, longest-substring, contiguous

Hello I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  LR ID           Kmer       ProcID
    1         GTACGTAT         10
    1         TACGTATC         10
    1         ACGTATCG          2
    1         GTATCGTT          3
    2         GTTACGTA         16
    2         TTACGTAC         16
    2         TACGTACT         16
    2         ACGTACTT         11
```

Output is something like:

```
LR1 max length: 16 #(as 2 kmers are consecutively going to proc 10)
LR1 min length: 8
LR2 max length: 24 #(as 3 kmers are consecutively going to proc 16)
```

There are 800 LR Ids like these which have kmers going to different processes. My objective is to find the longest uninterrupted sequence belonging to one LR ID going to the same destination proc id.
I need to compare the (k-1) characters of one row to its next and so on.

I know there is this function called

```
str_detect()
```

in R which checks to see if any pattern exists or not. I was wondering is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: @RonakShah I want to find what is the max and min continuous uninterrupted sequence for a particular LR ID going to the same process ID.

Comment: @RonakShah I have added some new rows and also gave a sample output. Let me know if that is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    count(LRID, grp = cumsum(ProcID != lag(ProcID, default = first(ProcID)))) %>%
    group_by(LRID) %>% 
    summarise(max = max(n) * 8, 
             min = min(n) * 8, .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#   LRID   max   min
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    16     8
#2     2    24     8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(LRID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Kmer = c("GTACGTAT", 
"TACGTATC", "ACGTATCG", "GTATCGTT", "GTTACGTA", "TTACGTAC", "TACGTACT", 
"ACGTACTT"), ProcID = c(10L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 11L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can count consecutive occurrence of `ProcID` in each `LRID` and count min and max in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(LRID, grp = data.table::rleid(ProcID)) %>%
  group_by(LRID) %>%
  summarise(max = max(n) * 8, 
            min = min(n) * 8)

#   LRID   max   min
#* <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    16     8
#2     2    24     8
```

Or using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(n = .N), .(LRID, rleid(ProcID))][, .(max = max(n) * 8, min = min(8)), LRID]
```